# Changing return value of Apache hook module

Tags: c, apache

I'm building a custom Apache module (a hook, to be specific) that checks for a custom authorization cookie provided by an external service, and then either validates and decrypts the cookie to get user information, or if not valid redirects the user to our custom login service. The main function is pretty straightforward, looks something like this:

```
static int verifyRequest(request_rec* req) {
  char* authCookie;

  if (!req->main) {
    authCookie = getAuthCookie(req);

    if (isValidAuthCookie(authCookie, req)) {
      /* do stuff, inject user data, etc... */
    } else {
      setLoginRedirect(req);
    }
  }  

  return OK;
}
```

So I want it to return `OK` if the user is authorized, I then inject user data (i.e. username) and do anything else, then I want the request to be processed by Apache as usual. However, if the user isn't valid I want to do a 302 redirect (by the way, if there's a better way to redirect the user from an Apache module let me know), as the `setLoginRedirect` function inserts our Login service's URL into the 'Location' field on the response header. If I try to return `302` from the `else` block, I get an empty response. If I declare an int at the top of the function and set it to `OK` (or `0`) if valid and then set it to `HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT` (or `302`) from the `else` block and then return the int at the bottom, I get an empty response. I've also tried using boolean values with an if statement at the bottom, and I've also tried doing the same thing by checking the header for the Location value at the bottom - both result in an empty response.

Any idea how to change the return value based on the if statement in the middle?